# How to get array data in correct sequence from serial port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

My purpose in below program is getting 16 bytes of data from microcontroller and processing data for appropriate instructions. There are a lot of related questions and answers here but I couldnt find anything about in below issue. I can get 16 bytes from MCU. Values of bytes are correct and I can see them in dataGridView but the sequence of bytes is changing . For example at first MCUData[0] = 0x01 , MCUData[1] = 0xFE , MCUData[2] = 0xCC then it changes to  MCUData[0] = 0xFE , MCUData[1] = 0xCC , MCUData[2] = 0x01. İt is like some problem shifting my datas in byte array. I am sure my MCU is sending data correctly because I checked in one of serial terminal program. My code is in below

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerialCommunicationMCU
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MCUData", "Byte Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MCUData", "Byte Value");
        }

        public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort SerialPc;


        #region Variables
        public string AvailablePort;
        public string[] Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        byte[] MCUData = new byte[16];
        #endregion


        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGreedByteNameShow();
            SerialConnectandRead();
            ConnectButton.Enabled = false;
            DisconnectButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPc.Close();
            ConnectButton.Enabled = true;
            DisconnectButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void SerialConnectandRead()
        {
            SerialPc = new SerialPort(AvailablePort, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            try
            {
                SerialPc.Open();
                SerialPc.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPc_DataReceived);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Serial Port Error");
            }

        }

        private void SerialPc_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPc.DiscardNull = false;
            SerialPc.Read(MCUData, 0, 16);
            SerialPc.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 16;
            DataGreedByteValueShow();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string port in Ports)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
            }
            DisconnectButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void DataGreedByteNameShow()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[0]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[1]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[2]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[3]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[4]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[5]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[6]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[7]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[8]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[9]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[10]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[11]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[12]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[13]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[14]");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("MCUData[15]");
        }

        private void DataGreedByteValueShow()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[0];
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[1];
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[2];
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[3];
            dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[4];
            dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[5];
            dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[6];
            dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[7];
            dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[8];
            dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[9];
            dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[10];
            dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[11];
            dataGridView1.Rows[12].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[12];
            dataGridView1.Rows[13].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[13];
            dataGridView1.Rows[14].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[14];
            dataGridView1.Rows[15].Cells[1].Value = MCUData[15];
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AvailablePort = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When binary data is transmitted without a message frame, the receiver has no way of determining the start and end of a message, much less the integrity of the data.  You need to wrap each set of data with a message frame (consisting of (at minimum) start byte, end byte and checksum or better a CRC), and create/send message packets.

Comment: You are setting the ReceivedBytesThreshold property too late.  That will permanently put you out of sync with the controller.  Good code uses the Read() method return value, counts off the bytes and resynchronizes by paying attention to the first byte(s) in the packet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx

> Reads a number of bytes from the SerialPort input buffer and writes
>   those bytes into a byte array at the specified offset.

```
public int Read(
    byte[] buffer,
    int offset,
    int count
)
```

Here's how your current code uses the function:

```
SerialPc.Read(MCUData, 0, 16);
```

Your buffer is a global variable defined as:

```
byte[] MCUData = new byte[16];
```

This is one way that you can use to solve your problem:

```
    List<byte> MCUDataOverTime = new List<byte>();        

    private void SerialPc_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPc.DiscardNull = false;
        SerialPc.Read(MCUData, 0, 16);
        MCUDataOverTime.AddRange(MCUData);
        SerialPc.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 16;
        DataGreedByteValueShow();
    }

    private void DataGreedByteValueShow()
    {
        if (MCUDataOverTime.Count >= 16)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[0];
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[1];
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[2];
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[3];
            dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[4];
            dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[5];
            dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[6];
            dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[7];
            dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[8];
            dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[9];
            dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[10];
            dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[11];
            dataGridView1.Rows[12].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[12];
            dataGridView1.Rows[13].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[13];
            dataGridView1.Rows[14].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[14];
            dataGridView1.Rows[15].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[15];
        }
    }
```

The code above would solve the problem where your values change over time.  **It's happening in the first place because every time SerialPc_DataReceived() is called, you've set it so that every "Read" will store its result in your MCUData byte array.  Consequently, it will end up overwriting your MCUData array since you've hardcoded the start-from offset to 0.**

That's why it looks like your data is being shifted.  You have to understand, fundamentally, these streams don't conveniently store data for you in the way where an index of 0 means the beginning of time (when the stream first opened and started).  If you want it to work that way, you'll have to store it yourself.

Please note that the code above does not attempt to empty the serial input buffer.  You're pulling 16 bytes every time you do a read when the DataReceived is called, but I wonder if the MCU is sending a lot more than that with every DataReceived message.

Edit:

```
    List<byte> MCUDataOverTime = new List<byte>();        

    private void SerialPc_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPc.DiscardNull = false;

        int readcount = 0;
        byte [] temp;

        do
        {
            readcount = SerialPc.Read(MCUData, 0, 16);
            if (readcount > 0)
            {
                temp = new byte[readcount];
                Array.Copy(MCUData, 0, temp, 0, readcount);
                MCUDataOverTime.AddRange(temp);
                SerialPc.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 16;
                DataGreedByteValueShow();
            }
        } while (readcount > 0);
    }

    private void DataGreedByteValueShow()
    {
        if (MCUDataOverTime.Count >= 16)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[0];
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[1];
            dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[2];
            dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[3];
            dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[4];
            dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[5];
            dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[6];
            dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[7];
            dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[8];
            dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[9];
            dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[10];
            dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[11];
            dataGridView1.Rows[12].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[12];
            dataGridView1.Rows[13].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[13];
            dataGridView1.Rows[14].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[14];
            dataGridView1.Rows[15].Cells[1].Value = MCUDataOverTime[15];
        }
    }
```

I'd increase the size of MCUData to 1024 bytes or more since 16 bytes seems kind of small.  The next thing that you'd need to do is keep track of the start and end points of each frame.  I'm guessing that it'll always be 16 in the case of your microcontroller but in general you should have the microcontroller throwing out null values or a special string of symbols to indicate the end of a message.

Comment: I added your corrections into my code but unfortunately it functions same. You are absolutely right. But I dont know how to make change in my code to avoid problems that you talk above.

Comment: What do you mean functions the same?  Once it's displayed, the data displayed in the datagridview should not change over time now.  However, if you're talking about MCUData changing over time, that requires a different thought process.  Because it is working correctly, but you need additional changes to the code.  The thing is, I don't quite understand your intentions with the code.  So I don't know what changes to make.

Comment: At the very least my current recommendation would be to, instead of reading just 16 bytes every time the DataReceived event is triggered, you should read the entire buffer.  The reason is because there's no guarantee that the serial port's input buffer is going to contain just 16 bytes every time the DataReceived event is called.  And that data isn't going to remain indefinitely.  Once the buffer is full, something is going to be discarded.  If you think that emptying the buffer would be useful, I can modify the above code.

Comment: I realized that at the starting , my code works well. I mean all 16 bytes of data are correct and in correct sequence. But when it performs 2nd operation , the sequence is changing. Your solution looks useful for my code. I think emptying buffer after each operation would be appropriate. I can use DiscardInBuffer() method but can you suggest me other effective solution if you know ?

Comment: I used SerialPort object from toolbox instead of identify in code, it works correctly now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then it looks like my solution wasn't the answer that you were aiming for.  Sorry to trouble you, but could you remove the answer mark?  As a sidenote, since you requested it I'll edit the above code to empty the buffer with each read.